# Why does this code only work when I use a break point?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, api, paypal

See code below, for some reason it only works when I put a breakpoint on line 2 (*) is there some delay? Is it starting the next line before it finishes the 2nd one?

```
dp.SSLCertStoreType = nsoftware.IBizPayPal.DirectpaymentSSLCertStoreTypes.sstPEMKey

*dp.SSLCertStore = My.Computer.FileSystem.ReadAllText(Server.MapPath("\cert_key_pem.txt"))


dp.SSLCertSubject = "*"
```

Note: The error is thrown on the 3rd line only when the breakpoint is set on the 2nd line, after releasing the break the program executes my paypal purchase via credit card.

I will post the error again I am replicating it now...

System error: Could not acquire security credentials: error 8009030E.

There it is, while it should say "Order Confirmed!" type message if working correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Almost certainly a threading issue, but nobody is going to be able to answer definitively unless they're familiar with `nsoftware.IBizPayPal`

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes you can find that breaking can mutate an object's state, due to the locals window evaluating object properties.  If they have a side-effect, then all bets are off, unfortunately :(  No idea whether this is happening in your case.

Answer (score 0):

I have no knowledge of ASP, so just wondering aloud: Could this be due to multithreading? You know when you put a break point you sort of freeze execution of all threads, but not so in the real execution.